# Solr Pharse match is not working with proper ranking

Tags: solr, solrj

I am working with Solr Search. When searching for phrase then ranking is not working fine. For ex if i search for "title:Graphic Designers Need" then title having all three first should come at top then having two words and then single.

I want results in below sequence:

```
        "title": "Specification Graphic Designers Need To Know Every Day",
        "title": "Graphic Designers: Insider Secrets from Top Designers",
        "title": "Graphic ElementsUnique Elements for Distinctive Designs",


<field name="title" type="case_sensitive" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="case_sensitive" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
           <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
           <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
           <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not mean "find all these words in the field `title`".

The query is parsed as "search for `Graphics` in `title`, `Designers` in the default search field, and `Need` in the default search field.

You'll have to prefix the field name for each term, or use `qf` together with (e)dismax. One option is to use `title:(Graphics Designers Need)`, or with edismax: `q=Graphics Designers Need&qf=title`.

Use `debugQuery=true` to see how the score for each document is calculated.

Comment: Thanks Mats for your valuable suggestion, It did improve the results. However, the desired should have titles with complete phrase come on top, then with the partial match and at last, having tokenized words. While with the given solution by you, I m getting results having the maximum occurrence of the words in the title on the top instead of a title with the exact match.

Comment: Getting this: "title": "Specification Designers Graphic need Designers graphic Need To Know Every Day",
"title": "Specification Graphic modeling Designers and their Need To Know Every Day",
"title": "Specification Graphic Designers Need To Know Every Day",
"title": "Graphic: Insider Designers Secrets from Top Designers",
"title": "Graphic ElementsUnique Elements for Distinctive Designs"

Comment: You can use the `ps`, `pf2`, `pf3`, etc. parameters to [adjust for phrase boosts through edismax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html#TheExtendedDisMaxQueryParser-Thepf2Parameter).